# Jquery table cell to input not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table

I am trying to implement an editable table using jquery. It is working fine but after I click it again it shows `<input type="text">`

To simplify problem statement :-

> 1. While I click in a cell it becomes editable.
> 2. When I click in another cell all cell values becomes `<input type="text">`
> 3. I am losing the values I input in one cell as soon as I click to another cell.

My fiddle is here :-
https://jsfiddle.net/6g9nwhqo/

jquery is :-

```
$('#editTable').click(function () {
    $('td').each(function () {
        var html = $(this).html();
        var input = $('<input type="text" />');
        input.val(html);
        $(this).html(input);
    });
});
```

Comment: http://mrbool.com/how-to-create-an-editable-html-table-with-jquery/27425

Comment: why not just add an `attribute contenteditable` on the td check this

Comment: where did you get this... I never heard of this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$('#editTable').click` will be called each time you click, so when you change first time, all `td` changed with `input`, when you `click` next time on `input` tag it gets propagated to  `#editTable`, you can use `$('#editTable').one('click'` as below

```
$('#editTable').one('click', function () {
    $('td').each(function () {
        var html = $(this).html();
        var input = $('<input type="text" />');
        input.val(html);
        $(this).html(input);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Try checking `td` for `input` element before adding

```
$("#editParamValues").click(function() {    
  $("td").each(function() {
      if (!$("input", this).length) {
        var html = $(this).html();
        var input = $("<input type=text />");
        input.val(html);
        $(this).html(input);
      }
  });
});
```

Comment: upvote, but for each click its going to iterate on all `td`

Comment: @JagsSparrow Could use `:not()` , `:has()` to prevent iteration of each `td` at each `click` event https://jsfiddle.net/6g9nwhqo/5/ ; not certain if `.each()` is utilized for other processes not included at OP